# How to pass an image from one composable function to another in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, image, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an app with texts and images. The images appear small, like thumbnails, on one composable (activity), alongside the text. The idea is: when the user touches (clicks) the image, the navigation component takes the user to a full screen version of this image in another composable (activity). Is it at al possible? If yes, how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the image itself, you should pass something to identify the image. For instance:

- If you're loading the image from the resource folder, you should pass the resource ID (i.e. `R.drawable.your_image`);
- If you're using the `assets` folder or some remote URL, you should pass the image `Uri` (i.e. `/path_in_assets/your_image` or `https://foo.bar/your_image`).

Then from the "ListActivity" you can pass the image ID to next activity using the `Intent` extras.

```kotlin
startActivity(
    Intent(context, DetailsActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("imageId", yourImageId) // resource ID or image URL
    }
)
```

in "DetailsActivity", inside of the `onCreate` method, you will get image ID and load it properly...

```kotlin
class DetailsActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // for uri ID
        val imageId = intent.getStringExtra("imageId")
        // for resource ID
        val imageId = intent.getIntExtra("imageId", -1)

        setContent {
            YourAppTheme {
                YourScreen(imageId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

finally, in your composable, you can load an image based on resource ID using:

```
Image(painter = painterResource(id = imageId), contentDescription = null)
```

or using [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/) for URL resource:

```
Image(painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(imageId), contentDescription = null)
```

Comment: Hi @nglauber, thanks for your response. I am trying to implement it, but in the "DetailsActivity" (which for me is a composable on a file different from "ListActivity") I get the following issue:  Composable
fun LoadImage(navController: NavController) {
    val imageID = intent.getIntExtra("ImageID", -1)
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = imageID), contentDescription = null)
}                                                                                                                                             The intent.getIntExtra won't work because it is unsolved reference...

Comment: @CarlosGomes you need to call `intent.getIntExtra` in activity's `onCreate`. And then, pass this information to your composable. I'm editing my answer to try to help you...